# Prove that a compact subset is closed by contradiction

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I want to know if my proof of a compact subset $A$ in a metric space being closed is correct please. Especially one step.

My idea was to assume that $A$ is open and to consider the following open cover of $A$

$$
\bigcup_{x\in A} B\left(x,\frac{1}{n_x}\right)
$$

Where $B(x,r)$ is the open ball centered in $x$ with radius $r$ and $n_x$ is the least integer such that $B(x,\frac{1}{n_x})\subset A$.

Then, since $A$ is compact, there exists $ 1,…,N$ such that

$$
A\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}B\left(x_{i},\frac{1}{n_{x_{i}}}\right)
$$

But $\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}B\left(x_{i},\frac{1}{n_{x_{i}}}\right)\subset A$, hence a contradiction.

I would like to know if my conclusion is not rushed. I do not see any problem so far but I have not seen this proof in my book thus I have some doubts.

Thank you a lot !

Comment: A compact set can be both open and closed, so you won't get a contradiction from assuming it is open.

Comment: I do believe there is one issue: A set which is *not* open, is not necessarily closed! For this reason, you cannot conclude that $A$ is closed yet.  Here is a hint: Prove that the complement of $A$ is open, by separating a point $ x\in A^c$ from $A$.

Comment: Steven Clontz made a very good point, and indeed, you haven't proven a contradiction. There is no reason why the union of proper subspaces of a topological space must be a proper subspace.

Comment: Thank you for your comments !

Comment: @legionwhale Even for finite union ?

Comment: @JuliusJ. Thank you for your hint, it was helpful !

Comment: Yes, even for $N = 2$. I'm sure that you would be able to think of any number of counterexamples. It's not clear to me why you would believe what you claimed to be true.

Comment: Yes in fact just take an interval and cut it in half… and I cannot infer nothing concerning the sub cover indeed.. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proof is not correct for a few reasons, as pointed out in the comments, but there is a proof which uses a sort of similar approach:

Assume $A$ is *not closed*. Then there is some boundary point of $A$, $x_0$ which is not in $A$.

Then define the open cover for $A$

$$G= \left( B\left(x,\frac{d(x,x_0)}{2}\right)\right)_{x\in A} $$

And then by compactness, there is a finite subset of $A$,

$$ A' = \{x_1,...,x_n\}$$

Such that
$$G' = \left( B\left(x,\frac{d(x,x_0)}{2}\right)\right)_{x\in A'} $$

Still covers $A$. However, if we let $x_1$ be the closest point to $x_0$, then there is some point $y$ in $A$ satisfying

$$ d(x_0,y) < \frac{d(x_0,x_1)}{2} $$

Which is then  not covered by $G'$, a contradiction. (You should fill in the details for this step)

Comment: Why not use, for example, $\overline{B(x_0, 1/n)}^c$? Or... $\overline{B(x_0, \varepsilon)}^c$...

Comment: @AndréCaldas I am not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: The sets I point for an open cover without finite subcover.

Comment: Carlyle... sorry for my comments! I realize that you demonstrated the way you did because you wanted to use a "similar approach". :-)

Comment: @AndréCaldas ah, no worries! Your method is certainly easier however, I hadn't thought of it before

Comment: This other method shows that the statement holds whenever the intersection of all closed neighbourhoods of an arbitrary point $a$ is the single set $\{a\}$. So, the complements form an open cover for any set $B$ such that $a \not \in B$. Finite subcovers would correspond to a finite intersection of neighbourhoods of $a$... that is, a neghbourhoods of $a$ itself. And those last ones do intersect $B$ whenever $a \in \overline{B}$.

Comment: @Carlyle Thank you a lot for your answer sincerely. It is a pleasure to see the achievement of something I was not able to do by myself. Concerning the details to fill : using the triangle inequality we observe that $\frac{d(x_1,x_0)}{2}\leq d(x_1,y)$ which implies that $y\notin B(x_1,\frac{d(x_1,x_0)}{2})$. Since $x_1$ is the closest point to $x_0$ we have $\frac{d(x_1,x_0)}{2}\leq\frac{d(x_i,x_0)}{2}$ for $i=1,…,n$ so the same argument as above can be used to conclude that $y$ does not belong to $G’$ I think. Let me know if I am wrong please.

Comment: @coboy, yes this is perfect!